# Magnification factor in image classification

Tags: image-classification, image-recognition, convolutional-neural-network

If a CNN is trained on images focusing on an object, will it also recognize when multiple such objects are present in the image?

For example can a network trained on single flower images also identify image having many such flowers in a bunch?

Is the answer same if situation is reversed? That is, can a CNN trained on bunch of flower images also identify single flower image?

Answer (score 1):

This question greatly depends on the pixel-space **scale** of the objects, but if the scale of the objects is similar and enough data are provided to curb overfitting, then **yes, it should work both ways**.

**The Caveats:**
A Neural Network is merely a glorified (hierarchical) [Template Matcher](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html). If the visual appearance of multiple objects in an image is strongly correlated with the learned template, those objects will each get a high response from that convolutional kernel. Convolutional templates can achieve some degree of scale-invariance through stacking multiple layers and using a downsampling strategy such as [Max Pooling](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Max-pooling_/_Pooling), but virtually all convolutional neural networks are practically quite limited as to the scale of features that they will respond to. As a simple example, a neural network consisting of two convolutional layers of 3x3 spatial kernels each with padding of 1 separated by a 2x2 Max Pooling downsampling layer would have a receptive field of at most 8x8 pixels per output location (3x2+2), where the last 3 is the last layer's kernel width, the middle 2 is the downsampling factor, and the last 2 is the input padding reachable from the first kernel's output. Trying to classify any objects larger than this would result in a failure to match the learned template, so in fact **CNNs are sensitive to the scale of their inputs**, but due to weight sharing across spatial locations, a strong response trained from a single item should activate for multiple items of similar scale and (to some extent) vice-versa.